# Simultaneous dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

If I know vectors **B** and **r**, and want to find vector **m**, knowing that all 3 vectors are coplanar, and **m** makes an angle $\theta$ with **r**, how do I find **m**?

I know that **m** $\cdot$ **B** x **r** = 0, and **m** $\cdot$ **r** = cos($\theta$), so I guess I need to solve simultaneously **m** $\cdot$ **n** =0 and **m** $\cdot$ **r** = cos($\theta$), where **n** = **B** x **r**. But how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the condition that the vectors are coplanar we obtain for some $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

$$\vec m=x\, \vec B+y\,\vec r$$

and from the other condition

$$\vec m \cdot \vec r=x\, \vec B\cdot \vec r+y\,\vec r \cdot \vec r=|\vec m|\cdot|\vec r|\cdot\cos \theta$$

we need some other extra condition to find $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Yes, I've just realised that there are two possible vectors (I think) that fulfill these conditions - I'll have a think. The problem I'm trying to solve, is that if I have a magnetic dipole moment and a position vector I can find B, the flux density, but if I have a flux density vector and a position vector, can I work out what the dipole moment is.